# Will the Documentation feature be made available on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Will the Documentation feature be added to all Stack Exchange sites once it is out of beta or only to some? Will we ever see it on sites like Gardening & Landscaping or Pets?

Comment: Unknown. It'll likely have to work out on the main site first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about other SE sites.

Comment: This question should have been placed on meta.stackexchange.com, but as Pekka commented, it's currently unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks for the info, was not sure where to post it but I found a right answer on Meta Stack Exchange. I will be deleting the question from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow (the company) would like to do this, but they are not ready for it any time soon.

Source: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281690/168333) by bluefeet on Meta Stack Exchange.